# NUSOAP - WSDL STYLE DOCUMENT/LITERAL

Tags: php, web-service, wsdl

Atualmente possuo 2 webservices rodando em hospitais que funcionam perfeitamente com o STYLE RPC/ENCODED porém vamos implementar em um software para uma fabrica e lá eles tem problema para consumir esse tipo de serviço.

Acontece que ao mudar para DOCUMENT/LITERAL simplesmente não acontece nada, não tem nada no cabeçalho de envio e nem no de retorno. Já tentei utilizar o soapUI porém ele só fala que tem um erro no WSDL e continua em branco.

Depois de muito pesquisar cheguei a conclusão de que ele não aceitava um complexType com a SOAP-REF:arrayType que é onde posso utilizar de array associativos.

Também depois de muita pesquisa achei esse tópico: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-whichwsdl/#listing6

que mostra uma estrutura WSDL com style DOCUMENT/LITERAL e a diferença para o meu estruturado hoje é que eu não consigo encapsular o element do modo que é feito no exemplo:

```
<element name="myMethod">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                    <element name="x" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <element name="y" type="xsd:float"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </element>
        <element name="myMethodResponse">
            <complexType/>
        </element>
```

O que eu consigo fazer é criar complexType e referenciar no element mais ou menos desse modo:

```
<element name='Pedido' type='tns:LayoutPedido' />
<complexType name='layoutPedido'>
<all:sequence>
<element name='id' type='xsd:string' />
</all:sequence>
</complextType>
```

o que não sei dizer se esta atrapalhando a leitura do mesmo.

Desculpe não poder postar o WSDL original.

Comment: e porque nao pode postar o WSDL original?

Answer (score 1):

O pessoal que não queria liberar ai como vai ficar intranet eu consegui pegar o arquivo.

Segue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<definitions xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:Integrate" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="urn:Integrate">
<types>
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:Integrate"
>
 <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
 <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
 <xsd:complexType name="itemLayoutStruct">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="itemLayoutArrayElement" type="tns:itemLayoutArray" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="itemLayoutArray">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="coditem" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="descitem" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="unidade" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="dtinclusao" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="dtalteracao" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="nomeabrev" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="descfornec" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="status1" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="status2" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="status3" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="origem" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="stintegr" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="gramatura" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="largura" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="comprimento" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="compxlarg" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="pesoliq" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="cor" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="prodlinhadagua" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="tipo" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="segmento" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="grupoprod" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="caracteristica" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="fabricante" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="agrupgtplan" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="fabricanteERP" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="nrfolha" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="nisuzano" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="tubete" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="codagrup1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="codagrup2" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="codagrup3" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="codagrup4" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="codagrup5" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="codagrup6" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="codagrup7" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="codagrup8" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="codagrup9" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="codagrup10" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="codagrup11" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="codagrup12" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="codfornec" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="familia" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="famcomer" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="grestoque" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="depositopad" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="fator_conversao" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="codemitente" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="embalagem" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="pesobruto" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="itemLayoutReturn">
  <xsd:all>
   <xsd:element name="STATUS" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="SUCCESS" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="ERRORS" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
   <xsd:element name="coditem" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:all>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="Integrate.itemRequestType">
  <xsd:all>
   <xsd:element name="itemLayout" type="tns:itemLayoutArray" form="unqualified"/>
   <xsd:element name="action" type="xsd:string" form="unqualified"/>
  </xsd:all>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="Integrate.itemResponseType">
  <xsd:all>
   <xsd:element name="return" type="tns:itemLayoutReturn" form="unqualified"/>
  </xsd:all>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:element name="Integrate.item" type="tns:Integrate.itemRequestType"/>
 <xsd:element name="Integrate.itemResponse" type="tns:Integrate.itemResponseType"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="Integrate.itemRequest">
  <part name="parameters" element="tns:Integrate.item" /></message>
<message name="Integrate.itemResponse">
  <part name="parameters" element="tns:Integrate.itemResponse" /></message>
<portType name="IntegratePortType">
  <operation name="Integrate.item">
    <input message="tns:Integrate.itemRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:Integrate.itemResponse"/>
  </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="IntegrateBinding" type="tns:IntegratePortType">
  <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  <operation name="Integrate.item">
    <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Integrate#Integrate.item" style="document"/>
    <input><soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:integrate"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:integrate"/></output>
  </operation>
</binding>
<service name="Integrate">
  <port name="IntegratePort" binding="tns:IntegrateBinding">
    <soap:address location="http://ecopack2/gtplan/webServiceDocument/item.php?wsdl"/>
  </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```